# Joining two table by mask

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have 2 tables **PAGE** and **SITE**. PAGE table has field URL. And SITE table has field DOMEN_URL. I want to join two tables on these fields. But I want to **condition of joining is that url of the page belongs to a domain url of site**. In other words an url of page should begin with a domain url.

That is, for example, a page with the url "http://mysite.com/blablabla" belongs to a site domain with the domain url "http://mysite.com". But a page with the url "http://other.com/translate?url=http://www.mysite.com" does not belong to the domain url "http://mysite.com".

This condition must be true:

```
POSITION(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(site.domain_url, '^(http|https)://(www\\.|)', ''), '/')
IN TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(page.url, '^(http|https)://(www\\.|)', ''), '/')) = 1
```

But I can not specify this expression in the statement ON of JOIN.

How can I solve this problem? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *
from page
join site on page.url like site.domain_url || '%'
```

Comment: I don't know of this operator `||` and don't understand such syntax. But it works properly somehow magically! I would be very grateful if you explain the working principle of this statement (**like** smbd **||** '%')

Comment: It's simple basic sql.  There's no magic at all.  "like" matches a string with a pattern, returning true if there's a match.  The operator "||" means concatenate.  The character '%', in a pattern, is a wildcard.